# Is there any way to track a url opened from chromes pop up blocker prompt. Probably using client side javascript or any work around

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frontend

[image: Chrome pop up showing up the blocked url]

Chrome by default blocks opening more than one tab with a single user action. While it is blocked you can go to pop up blocker prompt and open the blocked url from there as shown in the screenshot. Can it be tracked by some script to know on front end that particular url was opened ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you check whether the tabs are opened, if you open the tabs using javascript window.open(). When a tab is blocked, the function will return 'undefined'. See this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hco6xsos/

The main issue (only 1 tab can be opened on each user interaction in Chrome) is unsolvable so there is no workaround for that. Fortunately it is possible to detect whether they are opened.

HTML

```
<span>click here</span>
<div></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var links=[
        'http://www.economist.com',
        'http://www.google.com',
        'http://www.stackoverflow.com',        
    ];
    var txt='';
    while(link=links.shift()){
        popup=window.open(link);
        if(popup){
            txt+='opened: '+link;
        }else{
            txt+='NOT opened: '+link;
        }
        txt+='<br>';
    }
    $('div').html(txt);
});
```

Comment: @merjin: You are correct but i am looking whether we can track if the url is opened not by script instead it is opened by clicking on the link shown by the pop up blocker as you can see in the screen shot.

Comment: I don't completely understand this sentence but if you mean: a generic way to detect whether the user has just opened a url; no you cannot detect that on the frontend. The only way would be to add a token to the url (....com?token=XXX) and the server at the visited url will send that token to your current server to notify that the url has been visited, and then possibly you can push this info to the client

Comment: Yes, i was looking for something like this.